# Class members of different types, one for each enum variand

Tags: c++, templates, enums

I have an enum like this:

```
enum Field {
    Foo,
    Bar,
    Baz,
    // 50 more follow
}
```

I want to associate some data type with each value (Foo - uint, Bar - string, etc.), and I want to create a class with a field for each enum value, of a type associated with this enum. I'd also want to have a generic getter/setter that would allow to atomically operate on group of fields.

Is there a way to do all of that, in a generic fashion - avoiding specialized methods for each field, but retaining all the type safety I want? If so, how to do it?

Comment: _"Is there a way to do all of that, in a generic fashion"_ Yes there is. We have such stuff in our production code.

Comment: How about an example of exactly what you're trying to accomplish along with a use case.

Comment: I can you just tell that much, that the code is based on using something like a `std::map<Field,AbstractValueTypeWrapper>`.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: yeah, I should have known people here are going to take the question literally, giving a binary answer without any explanation how to actually do it... Gonna edit now.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ (second post): I can't use AbstractValueTypeWrapper because it requires either common ancestor in class hierarchy + RTTI for downcasting (neither being a possibility), or completely unsafe casts which is completely out of question because that will cause more problems than it would solve.

Comment: We actually use a CRTP and do all the type checks at compile time (it's meant for embedded systems). At the end we wrap `T` with a `void*` managed internally. It's way a too complex cluster of several template classes and base classes (besides it's our proprietary design) to write up a concise answer here, _how it works_.  Your question isn't much better than _"gimmie teh codez plz"_.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: well, the whole point of this site is "gimmie teh codez", isn't it? At least that's what it became in recent years.

I understand that you can't publish proprietary code you're using at your company. Though I'm not sure it would be useful in my particular case anyway.

Comment: @Xirdus _"well, the whole point of this site is "gimmie teh codez""_ Well, no . You're completely wrong coming here with such attitude.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: I only ever go to this site when I want a code snippet (not a copy-paste-ready one, but a general solution). Partly because I have other places to ask about more general things, where asking for snippets is frowned upon, and partly because even if I ask for a general explanation, all I usually get here is code snippet anyway.

Comment: @Xirdus Yeah, there are many people around here deteriorating  the quality of the site this way. They're called _help vampires_ and _rep hounds_ usually.

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, if you're going to do this, you're probably going to want to do this in two ways:

1) Create a new class.

If you're sharing 50 or so fields between common classes, you might as well create a common class or struct to hold the data.

2) Use a `std::map<variant/enum, value>`.

To me, if you really want to create a flexible system at the cost of performance, you could instead implement a key/value system using a `std::map/std::unordered_map`. Boost.Variant has a good implementation allowing for various variant types that acts as a more advanced enum. If you use this as the key, you can be sure that the map will only have an enumerated number of types and still remain type safe. Just beware of the issues with doing this.

Comment: 1) Creating a new class is the easy part. Mapping its fields to enums is much harder, and what I'm actually asking about here. 2) boost::variant eliminates the need for enum, but at the same time eliminates all the gain I would have from such enum - for example, atomically updating several fields at once in arbitrary combination, for which I need enum->mutex mapping.

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of any pure C++ solution which would meet all of your requirements. Runtime casting is not suitable for you due to lack of type safety, while there is no way (AFAIK) to iterate over an enum at compile-time and, moreover, generate a class member for each item. Even if there is some super sophisticated template-based method, in my opinion, writing some script that would generate C++ code out of your enum would be way more simple and flexible to achieve what you want.